# Updating object inside multiple nested array form with useState

Tags: next.js, react-hooks

I build ecommerce website with nextjs, I have product form with product data.

This is dummy data :

```
 {
    id: "1",
    name: "قميص لاكسوت",
    description: "فول كفر خامه قطن ليكرا",
    rating: 4,
    total_sell: 35,
    images: [
      {
        url: "/public/56774684-c63b-4835-b419-a330a61eeccc.jpeg",
      },
      {
        url: "/public/56774684-c63b-4835-b419-a330a61eeccc.jpeg",
      },
      {
        url: "/public/56774684-c63b-4835-b419-a330a61eeccc.jpeg",
      },
    ],
    category: {
      name: "قمصان",
      gender: "حريمي",
    },

    sizes: [
      {
        id: "1",
        size: "l",
        colors: [
          { id: "1", color: "red", stock: 10 },
          { id: "2", color: "black", stock: 5 },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        size: "xl",
        colors: [
          { id: "1", color: "blue", stock: 15 },
          { id: "2", color: "white", stock: 50 },
        ],
      },
    ],

    createdAt: new Date("2023-08-12T03:49:42.714+00:00"),
  },
```

I try to add size field and inside, I try to add color field.

I can't reach this colors array.

This my code for adding size field

```
  const handleAddSize = () => {
    const productCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));
    productCopy.sizes = [
      ...productCopy.sizes,
      { size: "", colors: [{ color: "", stock: 0 }] },
    ];
    setProduct(productCopy);
  };
```

When I try to reach color field with the same way it doesn't work

```
  const handleAddColors = () => {
    setProduct({
      ...product,
      sizes: [
        ...product.sizes,
        {colors: [...product.sizes.colors, { color: "", stock: 0 }] }
      ],
    });
  };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vpy1.png)

I tried several ways, but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a color to a certain sizes object on your product you need to update an existing element in your sizes array on your product.

The `handleAddSize` works because you are adding an entirely new size object to your product meaning no updating needed. So you can just spread and add a new object.

The solution:

```
  const handleAddColors = (targetSizeId) => {
    setProduct({
      ...product,
      sizes: product.sizes.map((size) => { //Replace size object with new object containing a new color if it is the one we are looking for. Else, return existing size.
        if(targetSizeId === size.id) {
          return {
            ...size,
            colors: [
              ...size.colors,
              { color: "", stock: 0 }
            ]
          }
        }
        return size;
      },
    });
  };
```

Going forward I recommend using TypeScript whenever you are writing React and NextJS applications. Helps catch and explain these kinds of errors before they happen.

Comment: Thank you very mush it's really confusing me ....

Comment: i already using typescript and it complain all time

Comment: Thats a good thing! Listen to it and learn. Its trying to tell you what you intended to do and what you are actually doing is not coinciding

Answer (score 0):

For elegance. You might want to try [`immer`](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer). Focus on business logic and let immer do the rest.